# How to improve precision of measure with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have recently wanted to measure the length of foot. I used a credit-card as a reference because the size of credit-card is known and stable (8.5cm*5.4cm), long edge 'cardL'. We assume the length of foot is 'footL'.

process:

1. Take a photo with foot and credit-card;
2. Get the contour of credit-card, and use minAreaRect function to measure the size of card, get long edge of card (cardl)
3. Use the same method to get contour of foot and get the length of foot(footl)
4. Use formula: cardl : footl = cardL : footL

eg. I took a photo as follow. I measured the length of foot is 22.4cm. the pixel length of foot in the photo is 2137.6. the pixel long edge of card is 763.14, so footL = 24cm. This result is imprecise. How could I improve the precision of measurement?

[image: eg. I took a photo as follow. I measured the length of foot is 22.4cm. the pixel length of foot in the photo is 2137.6. the pixel long edge of card is 763.14, so footL = 24cm. This result is imprecise. How could I improve the precision of measurement?]

Another question is when I take the photo in different height ( the pixels of foot is different each time, and the result 'footL' is much bigger than the real value as the height is smaller.)

Comment: For a simple implementation (as you're describing) your reference and your sample must be at the same depth from the camera, everything in plane and perpendicular.  And you can't move the camera between reference and sample.

Comment: and the foot fetishists go crazy

Comment: From the perspective of your sample image, where precisely is the "end" of the foot?  I don't see a sharp feature, indeed I see easily 1.6 cm of uncertainty in how to define the length of the foot.

Comment: why is the rect around the credit card much bigger than the card? In general you'lö get problema of  perspective distortion and prspective forshortening

Comment: @Micka The green rect is drawn manually. The yellow rect is drawn automatically by code.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot. I have tested a book instead of foot and got the right size of book.

Comment: how did you measure real foot length? as you can see in your image, the rect is going a bit over the  heel. Not sure whether this comes from the angled leg/foot conjunction. You should try to find out whethe the error comes from wrong rectangle or from perspective-foreshortening (since the foot is 3D it is closer to the camera = bigger in the image).

Comment: @deW1 er....It's not a foot fetishists.....It's just a coil used to segment foot and leg in the photo....

Comment: @Micka When I take the photo in 30cm height, the length in photo is bigger than foot length as picture above. but taking photo in 50-60cm height, the length in photo is approximate to foot length. This situation is  I take the photo by myself. The angled leg/foot conjunction couldn't be avoided. I don't know how to judge true length of foot.

Comment: from where to where did you measure the foot length (22.4cm)? Additional problems could be lens distortion effects, but it doesn't look like much lens distortion.

Comment: I measured the foot length with a ruler. I haven't thought the effection of  lens distortion.

Answer (score 1):

I like your idea!

A few thoughts; measure the length of the object in same the plane that is defined by the credit card. A possible way to do it:

- calibrate your camera (thanks @PSchn for the reminder)
- rest the foot in a normal position on the ground (not rotated as in the image that you provided)
- place the credit card next to it
- take a picture in such an angle that it includes

  - the entire credit card (no occlusions)
  - the dimension of the object that you want to measure, e.g. toe to heel in your case.
- apply a homography transformation to the image which converts the projection of the credit card into a rectilinear rectangle (of credit card size).
- finally, apply the formula 4. in your list above.

Comment: And don't forget to calibrate the camera;)